# undefined variables and indexes using Sessions to store arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session-variables

So Im trying to work Session cookies and arrays together and in the process page that i have going it works; I can index with the session variables and it will display the string from the database. However I am having issues with trying to display this in a table;

It does also grab the type as I am using the get method which is holding the identifier. so that part is fine.

my question is with my code, I am getting undefined errors and I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
if($type =="search"){
 echo $searchForm;
}else if($type == "searchResult"){
?>
<div id="Table">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Phone</td>
   <td>Email</td>
   <td>Department (if applicable)</td>
   <td>Industry(If applicable)</td>
   <td>Place Type</td>
   <td>Image</td>
   <td>Description</td>
   <td>Organisation Website</td>
   <td>Address</td>
  </tr>
<?php 
    
      //This works 
   echo "This is the name variable output ".$_SESSION['sName'][1];

    $searchTable = "
         <tr>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sName'][$var]}</td>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sPhone'][$var]}</td>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sEmail'][$var]}</td>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sDepartment'][$var]}</td>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sIndustry'][$var]}</td>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sPlaceType'][$var]}</td>
          <td><a href='{$_SESSION['sMapURL'][$var]}'>Map Link</a>'</td>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sDescription'][$var]}</td>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sOrganisationURL'][$var]}</td>
          <td>{$_SESSION['sStNumber'][$var]}  {$_SESSION['sStName'][$var]} {$_SESSION['sStType'][$var]}           {$_SESSION['sPostcode'][$var]}</td>
         </tr>";
         
  for ($var = 0; $var <= $_SESSION['numRowsSearch']; $var++) {
    echo $searchTable;
    }
 


?>
 </table>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You refer to the undefined variable `$var`. The string interpolation happens in the statement that contains that string literal.

Comment: I was thinking that last night, however I'm not entirely sure how to transform the code so it bends to both requirements if that makes sense.

Comment: Declare and use the `$searchTable` variable inside the loop.

Comment: So I tried that and it didn't like it

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply the term "like" to php. Update your code in the question as I recommended and explain in details what problem you have now.